# Update sharepoint online row when new item created in post route with custom connect rest API

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

Hello i have a MERN project that i want to connect the data to sharepoint online through REST API. I already created the custom connector that have get request and created a flow (its working). But i want to update the sharepoint row data with rest api post request, if new data is created with post request(in website) the sharepoint data will also update.

How to add trigger for this to happen ? i have zero clue dealing with microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend you to create a sharepoint event receiver to reach your requirement. A list instance event receiver responds to events that occur in any instance of a list definition. Although the event receiver template does not enable the targeting of a specific list instance, you can modify an event receiver that is scoped to a list definition to respond to events in a specific list instance.

To target a specific list instance, in the Elements.xml for the event receiver, replace ListTemplateId with ListUrl and add the URL of the list instance.

Please refer to the following article to create an event receiver

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5b1f04/creating-simple-event-receiver-in-sharepoint-2013/